# Header going over footer

Tags: html, css

I need help with my website
[image]

My 3rd header has gone over my footer.

My code below:

```html
    <div style="width: 100%; display: table;">
    <div style="display: table-row">
    <!-- ------------------------------------------------------------------ -->
 <!-- Manufacturing Division -->
    <div style="width: 770px; height:450px; display: table-cell; background-color:#17202A ;">
 <p style="text-align:center; font-size: 30px; color:white">Manufacturing Division</p>
 <center>
 <img src="board.jpg" align="middle" style="width:250px; height:150px; text-align:center">
 </center>
 <p style="font-size=10px; text-align:center; color:white">
 With more than 20 years of expertise in Electronics Manufacturing, <br>
 we are happy to be your partner for your electronics manufacturing <br>
 solutions and PCB assembly
 </p>
    </div>
  
    <!-- Plantation Division -->
    <div style="width: 770px; height:270px; display: table-cell; background-color:#2ECC71;">
 <p style="text-align:center; font-size: 30px">Plantation Division</p>
 <center>
 <img src="plant.jpg" align="middle" style="width:250px; height:150px; text-align:center">
 </center>
 <p style="font-size=10px; text-align:center">
 The division with land bank totalling of 4, 300 acres located at Sabah state in Malaysia
 </p>
    </div>
    <!-- ------------------------------------------------------------------- -->

    </div>
    <h5 style="font-size:50px">end</h5>
    </div>


    </body>

    <footer style="background-color:lightgrey; font-size: 20px; 
    text-align:center; font-family: 'myFirstFont', italic;
 color: black;">
 Copyright &copy; 2020 All Rights Reserved, SCOPE Industries Berhad
    </footer>
```

The "end" should be on top of footer.
If I zoom in webpage at 100%,it is under the footer.
If I zoom in at 80%, it is on top of footer.

The first part of the code is the middle 2 parts.
I need to add another part to this page, but can't. Also having the same problem on my first page

Comment: You mean the end element is not in the correct position? Where should it be then? This is not quite clear

Comment: run code snippet , copy right is down and h5 end up . but i suggest move footer tag in body .

Comment: It should be between the middle and the footer

Answer (score 0):

Check the below code when I add a header on that page it shows correctly!!

```html
<header style="width: 100%;background-color:green ;">
  Text
</header>
<div style="width: 100%; display: table;">
    <div style="display: table-row">
    <!-- ------------------------------------------------------------------ -->
 <!-- Manufacturing Division -->
    <div style="width: 770px; height:450px; display: table-cell; background-color:#17202A ;">
 <p style="text-align:center; font-size: 30px; color:white">Manufacturing Division</p>
 <center>
 <img src="board.jpg" align="middle" style="width:250px; height:150px; text-align:center">
 </center>
 <p style="font-size=10px; text-align:center; color:white">
 With more than 20 years of expertise in Electronics Manufacturing, <br>
 we are happy to be your partner for your electronics manufacturing <br>
 solutions and PCB assembly
 </p>
    </div>
  
    <!-- Plantation Division -->
    <div style="width: 770px; height:270px; display: table-cell; background-color:#2ECC71;">
 <p style="text-align:center; font-size: 30px">Plantation Division</p>
 <center>
 <img src="plant.jpg" align="middle" style="width:250px; height:150px; text-align:center">
 </center>
 <p style="font-size=10px; text-align:center">
 The division with land bank totalling of 4, 300 acres located at Sabah state in Malaysia
 </p>
    </div>
    <!-- ------------------------------------------------------------------- -->

    </div>
    <h5 style="font-size:50px">end</h5>
    </div>


    </body>

    <footer style="background-color:lightgrey; font-size: 20px; 
    text-align:center; font-family: 'myFirstFont', italic;
 color: black;">
 Copyright &copy; 2020 All Rights Reserved, SCOPE Industries Berhad
    </footer>
```

Comment: still the same on my end

Comment: which part do u need?

Comment: header part and also share a screenshot of your issue!!

Comment: Problem is at 100% zoom, "end" is under the footer. But at 80% zoom, "end" is on top of footer